# Is there a way to make Chrome's tab stay glowing on activity like in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extensions

Firefox and Chrome both glow or highlight a pinned tab when the title changes.  In Firefox the tab stays glowing until you focus it.  In Chrome, the tab just glows for a moment and then goes back to the normal state.

Is there a way in Chrome to make the tab stay glowing like in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/33rVaX7pmRE/arl1bLL98XkJ) on the Chrome Forum, it is not possible.